# Does Google Cloud Build tag trigger apply to all branches by default?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, google-cloud-build, cicd

When choosing Tag based trigger in Google Cloud Build, does that mean that any branch with that tag pushed will trigger the pipeline? How can we restrict it to a specific branch, i.e. only tags pushed to a specific branch will trigger the pipeline (tags pushed to develop branch for example)?

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb. 2022, I believe the answer to your question is (unfortunately) **yes**, any time you push a commit with the given tag, regardless of the branch, the build will run.

As to your second question, it doesn't appear that there are any built-in filtering options for both branches *and* tags. (There is no mention of this ability in the documentation for [creating triggers](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#build_trigger).) There is a way to [skip builds](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#skipping_a_build_trigger) by including `[skip ci]` in your commit message, but that's not ideal for automation. Depending on the constraints you have on your branch structure or tagging scheme; if those are flexible, you might be able to use a different set of tags on your develop branch.

One last option would be to add a `bash` build step at the start of the build to check the name of the branch (built-in substitution `BRANCH_NAME`) and kill it if it doesn't match some criteria. It's a bit hacky, but that's sometimes necessary with Cloud Build.